# How to resolve the error `org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout` in NebulaGraph Explorer?

Tags: nebula-graph

It seems that the HDFS configuration associated with my NebulaGraph Explorer is faulty.

```
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the HDFS datanode port 50010 is open.

If the port is not opened, an error similar to the following may be reported:

- `Check failed: false close hdfs-file failed`
- `org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /analytics/xx/tasks/analytics_xxx/xxx.csv could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication`